# MySQL - Combine with SELECT two tables

Tags: mysql, join, union

I have these tables:

**reg_movs :**

```
regmovs_id      id_car             date               status    
   1              1         2014-02-02 16:00:00         0
   2              1         2014-02-02 16:12:00         5         
   3              2         2014-02-02 16:22:03         0
   4              2         2014-02-02 16:45:14         5
```

**service_detail :**

```
id          id_Car                date_updated           price     
1             1               2014-02-02 16:12:00        45.00    
2             2               2014-02-02 16:45:14        30.00
```

I mean, when `status=0`, it will set the start time in my `SELECT QUERY`. And, when `status=5`, it will the endtime.

How can i make this query like this:

```
id_car     date         start         end                 price
  1     2014-02-02     16:00:00    16:12:00               45.00
  2     201-02-02      16:22:03    16:46:14               30.00
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you want a `SELECT` statement that will return a resultset of some form?

Comment: Something like this? SELECT start as time_somethingorother FROM reg_movs INNER JOIN service_detail USING (id_car) WHERE status=0 UNION SELECT end as time_somethingorother FROM reg_movs INNER JOIN service_detail USING (id_car) WHERE status=5

Answer (score 1):

You will need to first do a self join on reg_movs to merge two rows into a single row. Then you need inner join this with service_detail to pick the price of car. Below is a sample query based on the information provided for the schema.

```
SELECT t1.id_car
    , DATE_FORMAT(t1.date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date
    , DATE_FORMAT(t1.date, '%T') AS start
    , DATE_FORMAT(t2.date, '%T') AS end
    , service_detail.price 
FROM reg_movs AS t1 
    inner join reg_movs AS t2 on t1.id_car=t2.id_car AND t1.status=0 AND t2.status=5
    inner join service_detail ON t1.id_car=service_detail .id_car
```

You may need to change the query to use left join if you want to display records that don't have end time (i.e. they have only one record in the table with status 0)